# 64bit application in VS 2012 will not connect to Oracle 11g 64bit db?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g

I have a server, 2008 R2 64bit, with an Oracle 11g 64bit database on it. I am running IIs 7.5 and I need to connect an application that is compiled in 64bit to the database. I keep getting the "Need a newer version of Oracle Client". I have tried all 64 and all 32 bit clients and still get the same error... What am I not connecting??

Here is my webconfig connection string;

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=127.0.0.1)(port=7‌​536)))(connect_data=(service_name=ocfodb)));
PASSWORD=******;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;
USER ID=NCFMS_ACCESS_APPROVER" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

Comment: Two things: 1.Show us the code (how do you connect to the database ?) 2. When they say the client, they are probably speaking of the app that tries to connect to the database and not the database itself which is the server. 64bits or 32bits has nothing to do with the connection protocols.

Comment: Here is my code behind connection;     String query = "update NCFMS_APRVL_REMARKS set DATE_FULFILLED = :datenow, APPROVED = :approved, SIGNER = :signer, REMARKS = :remarks where NCFMS_APRVL_SUBMISSIONS_ID = :sid and DATE_FULFILLED is null and (";

Comment: Here is my webconfig connection string;    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=127.0.0.1)(port=7536)))(connect_data=(service_name=ocfodb)));PASSWORD=Qhag*(90;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=NCFMS_ACCESS_APPROVER" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />

Comment: A quick insertion here! The same application is working on a 32bit server flawlessly...

Comment: Are you sure that both 32bits and 64bits of the database are the exact same version ? It does not make any sense that the 64bits wouldn't work with a 32bits application. It does not matter what cpu architecture the program run because they use a protocol on top of tcp to exchange the data.

Comment: Just cornered our DBA and according to him the 32 and the 64 bit Oracle db's are 11g 11.2.0.30.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to install the 32bit oracle client to get the connection. Would think 64bit app to a 64bit database would require a 64bit client but apparently not!!

Thanks for all the help!